# Move existing DIV to dynamically created iFrame no jQuery

Tags: javascript, iframe

Trying to move existing DIV:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

to a dynamically created iFrame:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.name="newIframe";
iframe.id= "newIframe";
wrapper.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframeDoc.open();
iframeDoc.write("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
iframeDoc.close();
iframeBody = iframeDoc.body;
var iparent=iframeDoc.body;
var iparentDummy= document.createElement('div');
iparentDummy.id="dummy"
iparent.appendChild(iparentDummy);
```

That creates iframe outside of existing DIV "wrapper".

New iframe contains empty "dummy" DIV. However, attempt to move "wrapper" inside iframe's body tag to replace "dummy" DIV with existing "wrapper" DIV :

```
var dummyID = document.getElementById("dummy");
dummyID.parentNode.replaceChild(dummyID, wrapper);
```

throw an error

> Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the "dummy" div is inside the iFrame, the call to `document.getElementById('dummy')` will return null. `document.getElementById` only searches for elements within the original webpage document. iFrames are their own separate document. So your call to `dummyId.parentNode` is trying to access parentNode of null (since no dummy element exists in the original document), which causes your error.

You need to grab the "dummy" element from the iFrameDoc. Try this:

```
var dummyID = iframeDoc.getElementById("dummy");
dummyID.parentNode.replaceChild(document.getElementById('wrapper'), dummyID);
```

Notice you also need to modify the replaceChild call since the arguments are (newElem, oldElem), you seemed to have them swapped.

Comment: That throws an error:Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/1acfbew0/
I noticed in your original code you used ```wrapper``` instead of ```document.getElementById('wrapper')``` so perhaps you can try:(```dummyID.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, dummyID);```)